# What collection does Mongoose put things in?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to browse the raw data stored in Mongodb by Mongoose. Where does it go? I have a Schema called Profile with several profiles stored in it, but using the Mongodb shell `db.Profiles.find()` and `db.Profile.find()` doesn't return anything.

The Schema,

```
var Profile = new Schema({
    username      : {type: String, index: true, required: true}
    , password      : {type: String, required: true}
    , name          : {type: String, required: true}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default collection name when using Mongoose is the lower-cased, pluralized model name.

So if you're creating your model for the `ProfileSchema` as:

```
var ProfileModel = mongoose.model('Profile', ProfileSchema);
```

the collection name is `profiles`; so you'll find its contents as `db.profiles.find()` in the shell.

Note that you can provide your own collection name as the third parameter to `mongoose.model` if you don't like the default behavior:

```
var ProfileModel = mongoose.model('Profile', ProfileSchema, 'MyProfiles');
```

would target a collection named `MyProfiles`.